# Решить пример 38^29 mod 91 на C#

Tags: c#, математика

Пробовал сам сделать, но C# не может, такие большие числа обрабатывать правильно. На Python все ок работает. Вот такое свойство `(Math.Pow(d, e) % n)`  38^29 mod 91 = 12, а C# выдает 81

Comment: `x = 1;
for (i = 1; i < 29; i++) { x= (x*38) % 91; }
print x;`

Comment: _"Вот такое свойство (Math.Pow(d, e) % n) 38^29 mod 91 = 12, а C# выдает 81"_ - при определенных степени и делителе может и отрицательный результат выдать :)

Answer (score 8):

Ну, я в C# слаб, но, думаю, код на C/C++ вы переведете? :)

```
int s = 1, n = 38;
for(int i = 0; i < 29; ++i)
    s = (s*n)%91;
```

Можно воспользоваться более быстрым возведением в степень, типа

```
int s = 1, n = 38, m = 29, k = 91;
while(m)
{
    if (m&1) s = (s*n)%k;
    m >>= 1;
    n = (n*n)%k;
}
```

но смысл, я думаю, понятен? Применять модульную арифметику по ходу дела, а не только в конце.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуй использовать long ??

диапазон От –9 223 372 036 854 775 808 до 9 223 372 036 854 775 807 64-разрядное число...

long long2 = 4294967296L; - L обязательно.

int x = (int)L; - неявное преобразование int в лонг!

у меня так работает.

Comment: `38 ^ 29 = 6512148596632774597027306167797110812597813248` - думаешь влезет? думаешь в этом смысл задачи?!